# Site load takes 30 minutes after deploying DLL into local instance

Tags: development

Using `Sitecore 10.1.2`

Whenever I deploy a custom DLL into my local instance, the first page load takes more than 30 mins.
It could be any DLL.  I publish them in debug mode and there are no `*.pdb` files.
I do not see any errors in the log.

How should I go about troubleshooting this or is there any way to improve the page load speed.

Comment: Try running `DELETE FROM [EventQueue]` on both core, master and web databases.

Answer (score 2):

A few things you can try out to speed up local instances are as followed.

1. Add `optimizeCompilations=”true”` to the compilation tag in web.config.

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.2”>

With

<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.2" optimizeCompilations="true">
```

2. In `Sitecore.Xdb.config` located in `\App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB` turn off tracking and analytics by setting `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` to false
3. Turn off device detection in `\App_Config\Sitecore\DeviceDetection.Client\Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.config` by setting `DeviceDetection.Enabled` to false
4. Patch the configuration to make sure the agent doesn’t run every 10 seconds. It appears to be related to list management.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
 <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
 <scheduling>
 <agent type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent, Sitecore.ListManagement">
 <patch:attribute name="interval">00:30:00</patch:attribute>
 </agent>
 </scheduling>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

refer this for more details: https://www.symsoftsolutions.com/sitecore/tips-to-make-sitecore-load-faster-on-development-machines/

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following things along with the steps given in the answer:-

1. If you want to make your compilation more selective you can also set `batch` to `false` value.

   ```
   <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"  optimizeCompilations="true" batch="false" >
   ```
2. You can also consider to use RAMDisk for your compilation temporary files.

   ```
   <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"  optimizeCompilations="true" batch="false" tempDirectory="X:\TEMP\">
   ```
3. You should update file `machine.config` and set in node `/configuration/runtime` following value.

   ```
   <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
   ```
4. `Sitecore Performance Counters`. Counters store an information about number of different activities. They can be very useful but if you at particular moment do not need them, you can just turn off them.

   ```
   <setting name="Counters.Enabled" value="false" />
   ```

Read more details:-

http://sitecore.skowronski.it/sitecore/speed-up-sitecore-instance/